# Subprocess output to string in Racket

Tags: subprocess, racket

How would you implement the following procedure in Racket:

`(command->string "printf" "hello world")`

in such a way that:

- It runs the `argv[]` `'("printf" "hello world")` in a subprocess, finding `printf` in `PATH`.
- If the subprocess exits with code zero, returns stdout as a string.
- If the subprocess exits nonzero, raises an exception.
- Stdin and stderr are ignored; they are the same as for the Racket process.

Comment: Don't forget to post the code you've written ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
(with-output-to-string
  (lambda ()
    (or (system* (find-executable-path "printf") "hello world")
        (error 'who "command failed"))))
```

If you try this at the Racket REPL, it works but it seems to confuse the REPL, and the next prompt is not shown. I think maybe the `printf` command is peeking at stdin, or perhaps there's a bug in XREPL. Wrapping the expression above with

```
(parameterize ((current-input-port (open-input-string ""))) _)
```

seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I get the same behavior. No idea what causes it.

Comment: How does `with-output-to-string` work with subprocesses anyway? `(with-output-to-string (lambda () (writeln (file-stream-port? (current-output-port)) (current-error-port))))` gives `#f`.

Comment: I think `system*` sets up helper threads to move data between the current Racket ports and the file-stream ports created by `subprocess`. So `system*` doesn't care what kind of port the current output port is; it's just going to copy data to it from the file-stream port created for the subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (command->string command . args)
  (let-values (((sub stdout stdin stderr)
                (apply subprocess #f
                       (current-input-port)
                       (current-error-port)
                       (find-executable-path command)
                       args)))
    (let ((output (port->string stdout)))
      (subprocess-wait sub)
      (if (eqv? 0 (subprocess-status sub))
          output
          (error "Command failed:" (cons command args))))))

(writeln (command->string "printf" "%s" "hello world"))
```

In case anyone from Racket is reading, please consider adding something like this to the standard library. This is simple and quite commonly needed.

Comment: Perhaps one could make an issue on their public Github? They are a pretty open community.

Comment: This doesn't work from the REPL because `subprocess` needs stdin to be a file port (which I assume more broadly means "fd port" on Unix). The REPL `current-input-port` is not a file port.

Comment: FWIW: this was just merged a couple of days ago. https://github.com/racket/racket/pull/3468. It will be in the documentation for Racket 7.10 / 8.0. Though it's also a somewhat simple example.